# Why does LoadProperty not load the related entities for 1:N relationships? (CRM2011, early binding entity classes)

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

Suppose I have a custom entity `new_someentity` which has 2 other related entities: an "owner" entity which I'll call `new_ownerentity` (this is a N:1 relationship) and a "child" entity which I'll call `new_childentity` (1:N relationship).

I'm attempting to populate the related entities by calling `LoadProperty`:

```
new_someentity en = context.new_someentitySet.First();
context.LoadProperty(en, "new_someentity_new_ownerentity");
context.LoadProperty(en, "new_someentity_new_childentity");
```

Afterward, `en.new_someentity_new_ownerentity` is populated as I expect it to be with a reference to the owner entity, but `en.new_someentity_new_childentity` is simply still null.  No errors are produced.

What's the deal?

On a side note, is there really not a concise way to load a related entity for an IEnumerable of entities without needing to use `LoadProperty` on each entity individually?  This seems like a pretty classic case of an N+1 queries issue.

Comment: Long shot, but have you make sure that your new_someentity records have some new_childentity records?

Comment: @AnthonySteven you've actually nailed it. In trying to distill a different problem down I lazily used First() to get an entity, but what I didn't realize is that that particular record didn't have any children. My real problem was my assumption that if it had no children that LoadProperty would create an empty IEnumerable instead of leaving it null

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just because you think it should return an empty list when the object doesn't have any child entities doesn't mean that's the way LoadProperty works.

So for anyone else who comes upon this:

**LoadProperty will leave the property null when there aren't any related records for that record, even on 1:N relationships.**